# compound probability and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm stuck on a formula which looks obvious but that I fail to prove:

If $Z$ is a real-valued random variable with distribution $\mu$, $T_z$ is a random time for each $z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $B$ is a brownian motion independent of $Z$, why do we have
$$
P(B_{T_Z}\leq x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} P(B_{T_z}\leq x) \mu(dz),
$$
when the distribution of $B_{T_z}$ is well known for any $z\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

What I did so far is
$P(B_{T_Z}\leq x)= E(E(1_{\{B_{T_Z}\leq x\} } | Z))$ and $E(1_{\{B_{T_Z}\leq x\} } | Z)$ must be of the form $\phi(Z)$ for $\phi$ a mesurable function. All I have to show is that
$$
\phi(z)=P(B_{T_z}\leq x).
$$
One more important detail, for each fixed $z$, $T_z$ is a stopping time for the filtration generated by the brownian motion $B_t$.

I tried to show it with the definition of the conditional expectation, but I failed. I know it looks obvious but when it comes to details, I find it not so obvious.

This question arose when I tried to work out a proof in the book from Durrett ``Probability: Theory and Examples'' third edition, Theorem (6.1) (Skorkhod's representation theorem) p.399-401.

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: The idea is that $B_{T_Z}=G(B,Z)$, where $B=(B_t)_{t\geqslant0}$, for some measurable $G$, and that $B$ and $Z$ are independent hence $$P(B_{T_Z}\in C\mid Z)=h(Z),\qquad h(z)=P(G(B,z)\in C).$$

Comment: @Did, thank you very much for your help. This being said, I don't understand exactly how you get this expression for $h(z)$ using independence. Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: This refers to the general fact that if $(X,Y)$ is independent then $$E(u(X,Y)\mid Y)=v(Y)$$ where $v$ is defined as $$v(y)=E(u(X,y)).$$

Comment: @Did, thank you very much you solved my problem! I wasn't sure that we could write $B_{T_Z}$ as $G(B,Z)$ but now that you mention it I remembered that in the hypothesis I have $T_z$ is a stopping time for each fixed $z$ so I think you're right. Thanks again.